# How to list files modified by git pull/git merge?

Tags: git

in one of our projects, MysQL-Dumps are synced with git. One file for each table in the database.
After pulling/merging the dumps are imported to the local database with a hook. The problem is now, I need to find all table dumps that were changed with the pull to import only these.
How can I get the post-merge-hook to know, which files changed?
It is possibly not only one commit before that gets merged, usually, there are more commits.

How can I get a list of modified files?

Comment: This does it: `git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin/master`. I do not understand why the answers do not consider `git fetch`.

Answer (score 6):

`git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2`

Use `git log` to get git commit ids.
Use just `git diff SHAx` if you just want diff against latest head that you have pulled.

Before you `git pull` do `git log` or `git status` to get the SHAx. You can do `git fetch` instead of pull and do log and diff before you do merge.

Comment: yeah, SHA1 is my HEAD, but how do I get the correct SHA2?

Comment: You can probably explain your answer and articulate it with a description of what you are proposing.

Comment: This doesn't really help when you didn't get the commit sha before pulling

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I found is

```
git diff --name-only HEAD@{0} HEAD@{1}
```

since `HEAD@{n}` means the n-th previous value of `HEAD`

Comment: `HEAD@{n}` is the Nth HEAD from your *reflog* - it changes as you work (switch branch, commit, rebase, etc). It might have worked after doing something specific but It is only meaningful based on the previous commands you ran or the contents of `git reflog`.

Answer (score 3):

I used `git reflog` right after I did `git pull` to get something like:

```
SHA1 HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
SHA2 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from somewhere to anotherplace
```

the SHA right after the one reading "pull: Fast-forward" is the one where you were before the pull.

After that I used the `git diff --name-only SHA2` from the other answer, which will give you a list of files that were changed from that commit to your current state.

I'm not 100% sure how this works for pulls with lots of changes and merges, but for a simple fast-forward it worked very well.

Comment: actually `HEAD@{0}` (or the one reading "pull: Fast-Forward") is the actual commit - after the pull - and not the one before the pull!

Answer (score 0):

Right after you pull/merge a branch, you can see then changes form the pull or merge (i.e. changes introduced by the new commits/merged in) with:

```
git diff ORIG_HEAD HEAD
```

Else most merges will have two parents, `HEAD^1` and `HEAD^2`. If all changed tables were committed as a single commit, then most likely one of them is the master/source branch and the other it the hook's commit - all you need to do is show the changes with only that side, ex:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^2
```

For more complexe / criss-cross merges, it can be actually quite hard to untangle the changes. Git log has advanced options to select the most desirable path which depends on the change flow, YMMV.